# Using jQuery and Json to populate cascading select menus

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have a requirement to display data in cascading menus three deep, with all of the data being populated via jsonp (cross-domain issues).  There will be just one jsonp file (not separate for each submenu).  Moreover, the jsonp can (should) be loaded once rather than triggered by each successive select change.

I'm having a hard time with the jQuery, figuring out how to filter the retrieved data based on the parent select. Below is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<select id="typeFilter">
   <option value="" />  
</select>
<select id="typeFilter">
    <option value="" />
</select>
<select id="userFilter">
   <option value="" />
</select>
```

JSON

```
{"filters": {
    "productFilter": {
        "prod1": "Product 1",
        "prod2": "Product 2",
        "prod3": "Product 3",
    },
    "typeFilter": {
        "type1": 
            { 
                "Type 1": [
                    "subtype1": "Sub Type 1",
                    "subtype2": 
                        {
                            "Sub Type 2" : [
                                "subSubtype1": "Sub-Sub Type 1",
                                "subSubtype2": "Sub-Sub Type 2",
                                "subSubtype3": "Sub-Sub Type 3"     
                            ]
                        },
                    "subtype3": "Sub Type 3",
                ]
            },
        "type2": "Type 2",
        "type3": "Type 3",
    },
    "userFilter": {
        "user1": "user 1",
        "user2": "user 2",
        "user3": "user 3",
    }
}}
```

JQUERY

...this is the part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a go at trying to parse the JSON?

Thiss will help get started with some very simple jQuery examples: http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

This page will help you out with parsing the JSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON

Good luck